# Demo folder not found pyqtdeploy

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I am trying to deploy my pyqt project using pyqtdeploy using this https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/pyqtdeploy/demo.html
But i didn't found demo folder
[image: this is a screenshot of pyqtdeploy folder]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they don't include it with the installation anymore, you have to download the folder [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/hg/pyqtdeploy/file/e8041743a61e/demo)

Answer (score 0):

The demo folder of pyqtdeploy can be found online as [Parsa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14428983/parsa) replied.

The demo folder for the version you linked (pyqtdeploy v3.3.0) can be found directly on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyqtdeploy/3.3.0/#files).

If you struggle with downloading the demo folder, or following the instructions from pyqtdeploy documentation, I have created a Github repo containing a tutorial to generate a simple PyQt5 cross-platform app. The main tool used in the repo is actually pyqtdeploy.

Here is where the [Github Repo](https://github.com/achille-martin/pyqt-crom) can be found.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35816250)